# CuteSoft's Richtext Edit fails on firefox modal

Tags: javascript, html, rich-text-editor

Code bellow works fine in Chrome and Edge but fails in firefox. I'm getting the error "iw._ is undefined". This is because in default Rich text Editor config (rte.js) they check if the object is null in a[209] but, the didn't check is a is null. I can fix that, but the same issue is repeated several times and I would not like to change the base code from a library I am using.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <title>Document</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js" integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        Launch demo modal
      </button>
    
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
    
              <html>
              <body>
                <textarea id="inp_editor1">
                          <div>
                            <div>
                              <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:9pt; widows:0; orphans:0; font-size:9pt">
                                <span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'">es una prueba</span>
                              </p>
                              <p style="margin-top:9pt; margin-bottom:9pt; widows:0; orphans:0; font-size:9pt">
                                <img src="http://localhost:8080/t.001.jpeg" width="198" height="120" alt="" style="-aw-left-pos:0pt; -aw-rel-hpos:column; -aw-rel-vpos:paragraph; -aw-top-pos:0pt; -aw-wrap-type:inline" />
                                <img src="http://localhost:8080/t.002.jpeg" width="152" height="208" alt="" style="-aw-left-pos:0pt; -aw-rel-hpos:column; -aw-rel-vpos:paragraph; -aw-top-pos:0pt; -aw-wrap-type:inline" />
                                <img src="http://localhost:8080/t.003.jpeg" width="480" height="360" alt="" style="-aw-left-pos:0pt; -aw-rel-hpos:column; -aw-rel-vpos:paragraph; -aw-top-pos:0pt; -aw-wrap-type:inline" />
                              </p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                     </textarea>
    
    
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="richtexteditor/rte_theme_default.css" />
                <script type="text/javascript" src="richtexteditor/rte.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="richtexteditor/plugins/all_plugins.js"></script>
    
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  var editor1cfg = {};
                  editor1cfg.toolbar = "mytoolbar";
                  editor1cfg.toolbar_mytoolbar =
                    "{bold,italic,underline,forecolor,backcolor}|{justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull}|{insertorderedlist,insertunorderedlist,indent,outdent,insertblockquote}" +
                    " \#{paragraphs:toggle,fontname:toggle,fontsize:toggle,inlinestyle,lineheight}" +
                    " / {removeformat,cut,copy,paste,delete,find}|{inserttable,insertimage,selectall}" +
                    "\#{toggleborder,fullscreenenter,fullscreenexit,undo,redo,togglemore}";
    
                  var editor1 = new RichTextEditor("#inp_editor1", editor1cfg, { editorResizeMode: "both" });
                </script>
              </body>
    
              </html>
    
    
    
    
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>





  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      $('#myInput').trigger('focus')
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Besides, code bellow fails in firefox only in modals windows, it doesn't fails in regular windows.

```html
 <html>
              <body>
                <textarea id="inp_editor1">
                          <div>
                            <div>
                              <p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:9pt; widows:0; orphans:0; font-size:9pt">
                                <span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'">es una prueba</span>
                              </p>
                              <p style="margin-top:9pt; margin-bottom:9pt; widows:0; orphans:0; font-size:9pt">
                                <img src="http://localhost:8080/t.001.jpeg" width="198" height="120" alt="" style="-aw-left-pos:0pt; -aw-rel-hpos:column; -aw-rel-vpos:paragraph; -aw-top-pos:0pt; -aw-wrap-type:inline" />
                                <img src="http://localhost:8080/t.002.jpeg" width="152" height="208" alt="" style="-aw-left-pos:0pt; -aw-rel-hpos:column; -aw-rel-vpos:paragraph; -aw-top-pos:0pt; -aw-wrap-type:inline" />
                                <img src="http://localhost:8080/t.003.jpeg" width="480" height="360" alt="" style="-aw-left-pos:0pt; -aw-rel-hpos:column; -aw-rel-vpos:paragraph; -aw-top-pos:0pt; -aw-wrap-type:inline" />
                              </p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                     </textarea>
    
    
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="richtexteditor/rte_theme_default.css" />
                <script type="text/javascript" src="richtexteditor/rte.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="richtexteditor/plugins/all_plugins.js"></script>
    
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  var editor1cfg = {};
                  editor1cfg.toolbar = "mytoolbar";
                  editor1cfg.toolbar_mytoolbar =
                    "{bold,italic,underline,forecolor,backcolor}|{justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull}|{insertorderedlist,insertunorderedlist,indent,outdent,insertblockquote}" +
                    " \#{paragraphs:toggle,fontname:toggle,fontsize:toggle,inlinestyle,lineheight}" +
                    " / {removeformat,cut,copy,paste,delete,find}|{inserttable,insertimage,selectall}" +
                    "\#{toggleborder,fullscreenenter,fullscreenexit,undo,redo,togglemore}";
    
                  var editor1 = new RichTextEditor("#inp_editor1", editor1cfg, { editorResizeMode: "both" });
                </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how you can modify your code by delaying the initialization until the modal is shown, you give the Rich Text Editor a better chance to work correctly in Firefox modal windows

```html
<!-- Add an ID to the textarea for easier selection -->
<textarea id="inp_editor1"></textarea>

<!-- ... other HTML code ... -->

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#exampleModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    // Initialize the Rich Text Editor after the modal is shown
    var editor1cfg = {};
    // Configure your editor options here
    var editor1 = new RichTextEditor("#inp_editor1", editor1cfg, { editorResizeMode: "both" });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You are right, I really appreciate your help. Have a good one.

Comment: @EduardoRoque then could you please accept the answer?